# How do I specify the range to be executed in this for loop (R)?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm writing a small package for scraping lyrics. The problem right now is that it acts in a very clumsy way with no control. I would like to be able to specify what range to affect in the for loop that does the scraping.

I have two functions, one which presents the list of songs and the other that scrapes them:

```
songlist <- function(x) {
  url <- paste0("https://www.azlyrics.com/", substring(x, 1, 1),"/",x, ".html")
  page <- url
  songs <- page %>%
    xml2::read_html() %>%
    rvest::html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/a") %>%
    rvest::html_text() %>%
    as.data.frame()


  chart <- cbind(songs)
  names(chart) <- c("Songs")
  chart <- tibble::as_tibble(chart)
  return(chart)
}
```

This gives me a tibble like this:

```
  Songs                 
   <chr>                 
 1 Meet Me In The Hallway
 2 Sign Of The Times     
 3 Carolina              
 4 Two Ghosts            
 5 Sweet Creature        
 6 Only Angel            
 7 Kiwi                  
 8 Ever Since New York   
 9 Woman
```

Another function, called `songscrape()` takes a string argument used to build the url and scrapes all songs from that artist. It has a copy of `songlist()` inside it generates urls for Like so:

```
songscrape <- function(x) {
  url <- paste0("https://www.azlyrics.com/", substring(x, 1, 1),"/",x, ".html")
  artist <- x

  SongsListScrapper <- function(x) {
    page <- x
    songs <- page %>%
      xml2::read_html() %>%
      rvest::html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/a") %>%
      rvest::html_text() %>%
      as.data.frame()


    chart <- cbind(songs)
    names(chart) <- c("Songs")
    chart <- tibble::as_tibble(chart)
    return(chart)
  }

  SongsList <- purrr::map_df(url, SongsListScrapper)
  SongsList

  SongsList %<>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      Songs = as.character(Songs)
      ,Songs = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", Songs)
      ,Songs = tolower(Songs)
      ,Songs = gsub(" ", "", Songs)
    )

  SongsList$Songs

  #Scrape Lyrics

  wipe_html <- function(str_html) {
    gsub("<.*?>", "", str_html)
  }

  lyrics <- c()

  for(i in seq_along(SongsList$Songs)) {
    for_url_name <- SongsList$Songs[i]

    #clean name
    for_url_name <- tolower(gsub("[[:punct:]]\\s", "", for_url_name))
    #create url
    paste_url <- paste0("https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/", artist,"/", for_url_name, ".html")
    tryCatch( {
    #open connection to url
    for_html_code <- xml2::read_html(paste_url)
    for_lyrics <- rvest::html_node(for_html_code, xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]")
  }
```

As you can see, the for loop says  `for(i in seq_along(SongsList$Songs))`, which basically means all songs. Is it possible to be able to enter a range instead. Like if I choose up to 5 songs or from the 10th song to the 15th (based on the numbers in the tibble).

So the updated function call would look something like `songscrape("ironwine", from = 5, to = 15)` or `songscrape("ironwine", n = 20) #first 20 songs`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out using function overloading! If you notice, the number of loops is decided by the `SongList` dataframe. If we subset that by the appropriate amount, the loop should be done correctly. I won't post the full code but here is the gist:

```
songscrape <- function(x,y,z) {

#If only the string argument is passed
if(missing(y) && missing(x)) {
     y == FALSE 
                   }
#if only one numeric argument is passed
if(missing(z)) {
     z == FALSE   
                   }

#Now just modify the to fit the numbers passed. 

if(y == FALSE) {

      #User wants all songs

     } else if (z == FALSE) {

      #User wants top N songs given by the songlist() function. 
      #Slice the SongList data frame by y value

      SongList <- SongList %>% slice(1:y)

     } else {


      #User wants between a range, so slice between y and z.
      SongList <- SongList %>% slice(y:z)

}
```

Since the `for loop` uses the `SongList` dataframe to run through, the only thing you need to do is slice it appropriately and it'll run between those values.